# ffmpeg error: Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Muxer not found

Tags: macos, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

I am trying to segment a mp4 video file for HLS playback and I am getting the following error:

> "Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters
>   ?): Muxer not found"

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

**input command:**

```
sudo ffmpeg -y -i adwd.mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -force_key_frames 30 -map 0  -f segment segment_list adwd.m3u8 -segment_time 10 -segment_format mpeg_ts -segment_list_type m3u8 segment%d.ts


    ffmpeg version 2.8.5 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
      built with Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
      configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.8.5 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-opencl --enable-libx264 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libxvid --enable-vda
      libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
      libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
      libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
      libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
      libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
      libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
      libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
      libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
      libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
```

**Video information:**

```
General / Container Stream #1
    Total Video Streams for this File.................1
    Total Audio Streams for this File.................1
    Video Codecs Used.................................AVC
    Audio Codecs Used.................................AAC LC
    File Format.......................................MPEG-4
    Play Time.........................................9h 1mn
    Total File Size...................................588 MiB
    Total Stream BitRate..............................152 Kbps
    Encoded with......................................Lavf56.40.101
Video Stream #1
    Codec (Human Name)................................AVC
    Codec (FourCC)....................................avc1
    Codec Profile.....................................High@L2.1
    Frame Width.......................................426 pixels
    Frame Height......................................240 pixels
    Frame Rate........................................29.970 fps
    Total Frames......................................973039
    Display Aspect Ratio..............................16:9
    Scan Type.........................................Progressive
    Color Space.......................................YUV
    Codec Settings (Summary)..........................CABAC / 4 Ref Frames
    QF (like Gordian Knot)............................0.005
    Codec Settings (CABAC)............................Yes
    Codec Settings (Reference Frames).................4
    Video Stream Length...............................9h 1mn 7s 68ms
    Video Stream BitRate..............................15.2 Kbps
    Video Stream BitRate Mode.........................VBR
    Bit Depth.........................................8 bits
    Video Stream Size.................................58.9 MiB (10%)
    Video Encoder.....................................x264 - core 148 r2601 a0cd7d3
    Video Encoder (Settings)..........................cabac=1 / ref=3 / deblock=1:0:0 / analyse=0x3:0x113 / me=hex / subme=7 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.00 / mixed_ref=1 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=1 / 8x8dct=1 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=-2 / threads=3 / lookahead_threads=1 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=3 / b_pyramid=2 / b_adapt=1 / b_bias=0 / direct=1 / weightb=1 / open_gop=0 / weightp=2 / keyint=250 / keyint_min=25 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=40 / rc=crf / mbtree=1 / crf=23.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=0 / qpmax=69 / qpstep=4 / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=1:1.00
Audio Stream #1
    Codec.............................................AAC
    Codec (FourCC)....................................40
    Audio Stream Length...............................9h 1mn 7s 104ms
    Audio Stream BitRate..............................128 Kbps
    Audio Stream BitRate Mode.........................CBR
    Number of Audio Channels..........................2
    Audio Channel's Positions.........................Front: L R
    Sampling Rate.....................................44.1 KHz
    Audio Stream Size.................................495 MiB (84%)
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit  DoughnutZombie ! I was in hurry and did a quick cut and paste job to the information down.

Comment: Paste the full console report into your Q. Also, with `-vcodec copy`, force keyframes will have no effect.

Answer (score 1):

The error message appears to indicate that it can't find the segment muxer. You can check if it is enabled with the following command:

```
ffmpeg -formats | grep segment
```

It should output something like this:

```
E segment         segment
E stream_segment,ssegment streaming segment muxer
```

Comment: here is what I get Simon, does this look about right?                                 libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
  E segment         segment
  E stream_segment,ssegment streaming segment muxer

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this encoding problem by removing the forced keyframes (left over command from my original encode and setting the -flags -global_header parameter.

here is the final command I used:

```
sudo ffmpeg -i adwd.mp4 -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -c copy -map 0 -flags -global_header  -f segment -segment_time 10 -segment_list adwd.m3u8 -segment_format mpegts adwd%d.ts
```

Comment: Are you sure you need to be using `sudo` here?